# Getting a value from Another Form using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you get a value from one form in another form?
I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

Form1:

```
public TextBox TXT()
{
get{return txtbox1;}
}
```

Form2:

```
public Form1 frm;

txtbox2.Text=frm.TXT.Text;
```

Comment: Do you have 2 separate forms?

Comment: -1 for a poorly researched question. This is basic WinForms knowledge that is easily obtained, eg. in the MSDN Getting Started area: [How to: Retrieve Dialog Box Information Selectively Using Multiple Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56taefba(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Declare your Form1's txtbox1 Modifier as public . And in Form2 Declare the following:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
```

Then :

```
txtbox2.Text = ((Form1)f).txtbox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

**Form1.cs**

```
private Form2 secondForm;
private void GetSecondFormTextBox()
{
    textBox1.Text = secondForm.TextBox1.Text;
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
public TextBox TextBox1
{
    get
    {
        return textBox1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form2

```
public String txtval { get; set; }

txtBox2.Text = txtval;
```

Form1

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.txtval = txtBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the `Form1.TextBox1.Tex`t into a `Public Shared` variable and access the variable into the `Form2.TextBox1.Text`